# touchpad recognized but not working

Tags: touchpad

I'm new to using Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit on my laptop. I am not dual booted. My touch pad is not working and this is a big problem for me. Please help me solve this problem. When I display the inputs in the terminal this is what I get:

```
~$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Fujitsu FUJ02E3                           id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Fujitsu FUJ02B1                           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ FJ Camera                                 id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Try `synclient TouchpadOff=0` in a terminal window. That should turn the touchpad on in case it's been disabled.

Comment: Thank you for the advice but it didn't work. Please let me know if you have any other advice. I really want to use Ubuntu but will be forced to revert to Windows if I can't solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my linux computer. The problem wasn't about linux but about the firmware. Touchpad was turned off using fn-key.

I turned it on again using fn + f7.