# Touchpad recognized, but cursor not moving

Tags: touchpad, 18.04, synaptics

I updated to 18.04 LTS. (I am not quite sure whether this is the reason for the  problem, but since [this](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/nach-upgrade-funktioniert-touchpad-nicht/) and [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2322413) posts are describing the same problem...)

### My problem (symptoms)

- usb-mouse is recognized and works.
- internal touchpad (more info: scroll down) is recognized, but cursor is not moving

### My system

- XUbuntu 18.04 LTS (I just updated to `4.15.0-22-generic`)
- Acer laptop (TravelMate 117B)
- normally, I run touchpad-indicator, but I stopped it.

### What does that mean, `touchpad is recognized`?

- in `settings` -> `mouse and touchpad` it's named as `SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad`. It is enabled.

You need additional information? Ask me, I will add it.

### I tried any of the following:

- [`synclient TouchpadOff=0`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245606/touchpad-recognized-but-not-working)
- [`sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/901303/touchpad-recognized-as-imps-2-synaptics-touchpad-and-touchpad-options-do-not-w)

This didn't help.

Comment: `synclient TouchpadOff=0` worked for me! hope you got it resolved :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it by typing <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>f7</kbd>. (icon shows hand on rectangle)

Comment: My Dell Latitude has F7 mapped to Screen Brightness

Answer (score -1):

Just solve the issues. I think that portable mouse and keyboard users will face these types of issues because of the inactive of your mouse. So the mouse setting automatically turns of the mouse setting so kindly check that first
. if that helps cheers. the key for turning on is  Fn +f7. maybe it will be helpful.